# Creating random numbers that their average be equal to M

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have N numbers in M columns that were created from 1 to 100 randomly. `randbetween (1;100)`.
I got their mean. Now having the mean of N numbers I want create from 1 to 100 randomly that their averags be equal to Mean (inversely)
[Attached file]

Comment: Is your intent that the numbers in column M1 have a mean of 1, the numbers in column M2 have a mean of 2, etc?

Answer (score 4):

1. Create `N` random numbers.
2. Calculate the average => `A`.
3. Add `M-A` to the random numbers you've generated.

Comment: OP defines `M` as the number of columns. I'm assuming you intend it as the target mean. Nonetheless very elegant solution +1

Comment: In fact, I'm looking for N numbers whose their average are equal to target mean

Answer (score 1):

I have found the code that creates random numbers by target sum.

```
 Function RandTot(iTot As Long, iLo As Long, iHi As Long, _
                 Optional bVol As Boolean = False) As Variant
    Dim nNum        As Long
    Dim i           As Long
    Dim ad()        As Double
    Dim iTry        As Long
    If bVol Then Application.Volatile
    With Application.Caller
        If .Rows.Count > 1 And .Columns.Count > 1 Then
            RandTot = "Enter as row or column vector only!"
            Exit Function
        End If
        nNum = .Count
    End With
    If iHi < iLo Or _
       iTot < nNum * iLo Or _
       iHi > iTot Then
        RandTot = CVErr(xlErrValue)
        Exit Function
    End If
    ReDim ad(1 To nNum)
    Randomize
    With WorksheetFunction
        Do
            iTry = iTry + 1
            If iTry > 200 Then
                RandTot = "Time-out"
                Exit Function
            End If
            For i = 1 To nNum - 1
                ad(i) = RandBetw(iLo, iHi)
            Next i
            ad(i) = iTot - .Sum(ad) + ad(i)
        Loop Until .Min(ad) >= iLo And .Max(ad) <= iHi
    End With
    RandTot = ad
End Function
Function RandBetw(iLo, iHi) As Long
    RandBetw = (Rnd * (iHi - iLo) + Rnd * (iHi - iLo) + Rnd * (iHi - iLo)) / 4 + iLo
End Function
```

First I multiply target average in N then I use this code, but sometimes giving me Time-Out.